# onDragEnter event not working in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular1 in my app. Need to trigger a function when user drags some file to a specific area (div). I have tried ondragenter, but the function defined in controller is not accessible in this case. Tough, the alert function in ondragenter works. Is there any substitute in Angular1 for onDragEnter? Or, how can I create a new directive for the same?

Answer (score 1):

In the project I'm working I have an example of drag and drop to a file input. Maybe it can help you. In this case, I'm importing an Excel worksheet to the ui-grid in my app. But you could call any directive at all.

In the HTML, this is my input:

```
<label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
      Upload file
   <input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.ods" fileread="" opts="vm.gridOptions" multiple="false" />
</label>
```

This is the first half of the directive called after the input (the rest of the directive is just my application importation logic):

```
.directive("fileread", [function() {
return {
    scope: {
        opts: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, $elm, $attrs) {
        $elm.on('change', function(changeEvent) {

            var reader = new FileReader();
            //var evt = evt;
            reader.onload = function(evt) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {

                    var myEvent = ((window.event)?(event):(evt));
                    //get the Element which this event is all about 

                    var Element = ((window.event)?(event.srcElement):(evt.currentTarget));

                    var data = Element.result;

                    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                        type: 'binary'
                    });

                    var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);
```

The directive code itself isn't important for your case, but note that I reference **fileread** as an attribute in the input.

For an working example, see this Plunker (It's a simplified version of my directive, but it's the base I used):

http://embed.plnkr.co/rYC3nd7undqJz2mr8Old/

Hope it helps.